# How to break only one nested loop?

Tags: python-3.x

My code appears like this:

```
shop = input("Do you want to enter the shop?")
    if shop == "y":
        print ("["+shopownername+"]: Welcome to my store.")
        sleep(1)
        print ("["+shopownername+"]: Here are the items for sale:")
        for x in shopitems:
            print (x)
        sleep(1)
        print ("You have "+str(gold)+" gold.")
        sleep(1)
        choice = 0
        while choice != "exit":
            choice = input("What would you like to buy? Type 'exit' and enter to leave.")
            if choice == "a":
                purchase = "a"
                confirm = input("Are you sure you want to buy "+purchase+"? (y/n)")
                if confirm == "y":
                    if "a" in weapons:
                        print ("You already have that.")
                        break
                    elif gold < shopitems[purchase]:
                        print ("You do not have enough gold for that.")
                        break
                    else:
                        gold = gold - shopitems[purchase]
                        weapons.append("a")
                        print ("You have purchased the "+purchase+".")
                        print ("You now have "+str(gold)+" gold.")
                        break
            elif choice == "b":
                purchase = "b"
                confirm = input("Are you sure you want to buy "+purchase+"? (y/n)")
                if confirm == "y":
                    if "b" in weapons:
                        print ("You already have that.")
                        break
                    elif gold < shopitems[purchase]:
                        print ("You do not have enough gold for that.")
                        break
                    else:
                        gold = gold - shopitems[purchase]
                        weapons.append("b")
                        print ("You have purchased the "+purchase+".")
                        print ("You now have "+str(gold)+" gold.")
                        break
        else:
            print ("["+shopownername+"]: Thank you for coming.")
    else:
        print ("You did not enter the shop.")
```

What it is supposed to do is that in any case until you exit the shop, you will be able to buy items. However, in this system, it breaks the while as well, and proceeds to the next piece of code. What I should be able to do is try to buy a, and no matter if I cannot afford it, already own it, or have bought it, can both attempt to buy b or try to re-buy a.
What should I do?

Comment: `break` will only break out of 1 loop

Comment: [`continue`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm) if you want to skip the current iteration